# PermissionError: Python

Tags: python, permissions

I was wondering if there is any way in which I can get sudo access. This will only work on Linux.

```
# get machine's username 
userMachine = getpass.getuser()

# education > school's name > year
makeSchoolPath = "/home/userMachine/Education/schoolInput/str(yearCourse)" 
os.makedirs(makeSchoolPath)

# last path, but also creates a leaf directory for each subject
dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict.items():
    dict2 ['path' + value] = "/home/userMachine/Education/schoolInput/str(yearCourse/value"
    for value2 in dict2.values():
        os.mkdir(value2)
```

I got the error: "Exception has occurred: PermissionError [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/userMachine'". I read that I should write

```
chown -R user-id:group-id /path/to/the/directory
```

but I don't want to mess up anything, and I'm a little bit scared of that since it means "change owner".

Thank you for reading good human being :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, then just run your code with `sudo python <your file name.py>`.

Comment: I'd like to do it inside the code. I want it to be automatically working on every machine. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure if you type “sudo python file.py” your code should have sudo perms. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can do it inside the code?

Comment: I found this solution. (Note I might have styled quotes) ```os.system(‘echo %s | sudo -S %s’ % (password, command))```